# private constructor with STL container deque

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class Table using std::deque

```
class Table {
public:
Table():columns_(10) {};
private:
  std::deque<Column> columns_
}
```

I want that **only class Table** can initialize the class column so i do something like below

```
class Column  {
private:
int a_;
friend class Table;
Column(): a_(1) {};
}
```

during compilation the STL container complains that the constructor of Columns class is private , which i understand, but is there another way to ensure that only class Table can initialize class Column and still be able to use it inside an STL container.

Comment: the Standard has container requirements, and among them are that your elements should be Assignable and CopyConstructable. You should have a really good use case to circumvent that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your particular case it’s enough to add the following declaration to `Column`:

```
friend class std::deque<Column>;
```

In general, if you want to have such a pattern you simply cannot pre-size the container, you need to add the readily-constructed objects one by one.

On containers which support this (such as `std::vector`) you can, however, use `reserve` followed by `push_back`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `std::deque<std::unique_ptr<Column>> columns_` and let `Table` construct the columns and fill the deque

e.g.

```
class Table 
{
public:
    Table()
        : columns_(10) 
    {};

    void addColumn()
    {
        columns.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Column>(new Column));
    };

private:
    std::deque<std::unique_ptr<Column>> columns_
}
```